# FTDI chip supported Android device

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, usb-drive, ftdi

I am working on an Android programming. I decide to use FTDI chip for usb serial converter. My  android device kernel version: 3.0.8 and android version: 4.0.3 onyo nanopad 7 tablet. I research FTDI chip and read http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/TechnicalNotes/TN_147_Java_D2xx_for_Android.pdf and http://www.ftdichip.com/Documents/AppNotes/AN_134_FTDI_Drivers_Installation_Guide_for_MAC_OSX.pdf. I applied the squence of step but I don't achieve the connection between my android tablet and FT232BL ftdi chip using FTDI D2XX Demo app.

I would be grateful for your help?

Answer (score 0):

FTDI donot support FT232BL using their android libraries.. It's an obsolete product.

Reference: device_filter.xml

```
<usb-device vendor-id="1027" product-id="24577" /> <!-- FT232RL -->
<usb-device vendor-id="1027" product-id="24596" /> <!-- FT232H -->
<usb-device vendor-id="1027" product-id="24592" /> <!-- FT2232C/D/HL -->
<usb-device vendor-id="1027" product-id="24593" /> <!-- FT4232HL -->
<usb-device vendor-id="1027" product-id="24597" /> <!-- FT230X -->
<usb-device vendor-id="1412" product-id="45088" /> <!-- REX-USB60F -->
```

You need to search if someone has added support for FT232BL. Couldn't find it myself up till now.